# Forcing a Managed DLL assembly into a namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, dll, managed-c++

I'm dealing with a buggy, proprietary managed C++ DLL that is injecting come objects into the `std` namespace (it's included in the project as a Reference Assembly).

Unfortunately, it's injecting an object named `std::errc` into the `std` namespace, which means that the DLL won't play nicely with the new C++11 [`std::errc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc). Right now, my project can't be compiled if I include `<string>`, `<iostream>`, `<fstream>`, and probably other stdlib headers I haven't found.

Is there any way to force a DLL to be put in a sub-namespace? Or really, any way to prevent a Assembly Reference from overriding certain components of `std`?